# Comparing two boolean cells with nested IF functions with AND functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two cells, for this example A1 and B1 that take the values TRUE and FALSE. They are the boolean values not just text values. I want to create an IF function to capture the four variations of the two cells. That is TRUE TRUE, TRUE FALSE, FALSE TRUE, and FALSE FALSE. The function will assign a value to C1 based on the values in A1 and B1. The function I am trying to use is `=IF(AND(A1 = FALSE, B1 = FALSE), "Out of Scope",IF(AND(A1 = TRUE, B1 = TRUE), TRUE, IF(AND(A1 = TRUE, B1 = FALSE), FALSE, IF(AND(A1 = FALSE, B2 = TRUE), TRUE, "ERROR"))))`. This function works as intended for three cases but for FALSE TRUE it returns the final default "ERROR" value rather than TRUE. I have attempted rewriting and reordering the function but it always breaks in the same fashion. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: you have a typo in the final AND you have `B2` instead of `B1`, and after fixing that I cannot replicate your problem

Comment: Well I feel foolish. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Also by the logic above the following will do what you want: `=IF(B1+A1,B1, "Out of Scope")`  `Error` will only happen if there is something beside TRUE/FALSE, so you could probably do: `=IFERROR(IF(B1+A1,B1, "Out of Scope"),"Error")` also.

Comment: And further to @ScottCraner 's comment.  There should not be any conditional testing of A1 or B1 because they are already the Boolean result for which you are testing them.  `A1=TRUE` returns the identical value of just `A1`.  `if true = true, then true, else false` is a statement that never needs be written in any language and that is what your conditional tests are doing.  `AND(A1=FALSE,B1=FALSE` is just `AND(A1,B1)`.  Since you want to differentiate TRUE/FALSE from FALSE/TRUE you would use `AND(A1,NOT(B1))` and `AND(NOT(A1),B1)` instead of OR().